# XSLT mod check for large numbers

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xpath, modulus

I'm trying to do a modulus 11 check in XSLT 1.0 for a 17 digit number. However, it always seems to give the wrong output.

The only information I've been able to find about this, was in [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/483324/XML/XSL-mod-Operation-gives-wrong), however, no solution was found.

I have in the past used an XSLT template for a Luhn checker, I realise that this works differently to a modulus check but I was wondering if anyone was aware of an XSLT template which can calculate moduluses of large numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution which calculates  `$n mod 11` for integer `$n` of any size**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:call-template name="mod11"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="mod11">
  <xsl:param name="pN" select="."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($pN > 9999999999999999)">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pN mod 11"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vLen" select="string-length($pN)"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vLen1" select="$vLen -1"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vPart1" select=
          "substring($pN, 1, $vLen1)"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vPart2" select=
          "substring($pN, $vLen1 +1)"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vMod1">
       <xsl:call-template name="mod11">
         <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="$vPart1"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vMod2" select="$vPart2 mod 11"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="(10*$vMod1 + $vMod2) mod 11"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>12345678901234567</t>
```

**the wanted correct result (`12345678901234567 mod 11`) is produced**:

```
9
```

**Do note**:

1. This solution can easily be generalized to calculate `$n mod $m` for any integer `$m` -- just pass `$m` as a second parameter.
2. Another generalization is to pass as parameter the limit above which `$n mod $m` cannot be calculated directly using the `mod` operator. This can be useful when using XSLT 2.0 and having `$n` as either `xs:integer` or `xs:decimal`.
3. Another alternative is to use the Saxon.NET XSLT 2.0 processor or any other XSLT 2.0 processor that implements Big Integer arithmetics. Then the solution is just to use the `mod` operator:

....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(.) mod 11"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied with Saxon 9.1.07 on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced:

```
9
```

Comment: Interesting! However, when I tried to generalise it, and tested it with "mod 7", it gave the answer as 4 when I believe the answer is 0. Admittedly I may have made a mistake in my code change in generalizing it though.

Comment: @TimC: I'll look into this when I have some free time.

Comment: @TimC: There was an error, indeed. Now corrected and when you just replace 11 with 7 the answer is now 0.

Comment: @m4rc: Please, note that I found an error in the original solution and fixed it -- the answer is now updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That is because in MSXML number type is equivalent of .NET `Double` datatype, which has precision of 15-16 digits.
Try this sample:

```
double d = 123456789012345678;
Console.WriteLine("{0:f}", d);
Console.WriteLine("{0:f}", d + 1);
Console.WriteLine("{0:f}", d % 3);

long l = 123456789012345678;
Console.WriteLine(l);
Console.WriteLine(l + 1);
Console.WriteLine(l % 3);
```

Output:

```
123456789012346000,00
123456789012346000,00
2,00
123456789012345678
123456789012345679
0
```

I think you can extend XSLT with C# or JScript, because MSXML supports this.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx(v=VS.100).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx

Comment: That explains why it's happening but is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: There is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution to this problem -- see my answer.